# Ubuntu with thunderbolt 3 port for dual external displays

Tags: 16.04, multiple-monitors, dell, xps, thunderbolt

- Set up: Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
- Kernel : 4.9.0-040900rc7-generic
- Machine : Dell Xps 9360
- Docking : Thinkpad thunderbolt 3 docking station

I want to connect the docking station and make it work for a dual display set up. The displays are not recognised in `xranrd` neither can thunderbolt be found in `/sys/bus/`. Usb not recognised either. Bios changed to allow thunderbolt 3. Charging however works.

Anyone undertaken this task?

I have updated my BIOS to the current version (2.5) and the kernel to 4.14. This did not help.

Comment: Have you tried turning off Thunderbolt Security in the BIOS? Currently, there's extremely limited support for the Thunderbolt Port Security in Ubuntu. Redhat devs are working on a software called Bolt that will hopefully fix the problem in the future.

Comment: yeah first thing that came to mind!  Did that, would have been such an easy fix!

Comment: Which version of Kernel 4.14.xx? Note 4.14.36 and 4.14.37 are **broken for sure** so don't install them or you'll have to manually fix `apt` database.

Answer (score 0):

Gonna take a guess at you connecting via DisplayPort; the following is the steps I took to get support for DisplayPort and all my peripherals using the TB16 Dell Dock (hopefully these steps still help)

- apt upgrade, apt update, etc
- updated BIOS to newest version
- updated Kernal to 4.16.6 (More support for TB added at some point between 4.13, the first with tb3 support, and 4.16.6)
- turned on user level TB security in BIOS

YMMV